# Jenkins - Cannot find any credentials with id xxx

Tags: jenkins

Hi I have defined global credential like in here:

[image]

But when you go to configuration of specific job it cannot be found:

[image]

What can be the issue? What is more strange is it consumed when pipeline is run:

[image]